# How to check if a Datatable is Null or Nothing

Tags: vb.net, datatable, nullreferenceexception

How can I check if a `DataTable` has never been set, meaning it will be `Null` or `Nothing`? I don't mean an empty `DataTable`.

For example:

```
Dim dt As DataTable = TryCast(Session("dt"), DataTable)

If dt.Rows.Count <> 0 Then
    'Do something !
End If
```

If `Session("dt")`has never been set or is lost in memory for some reason, `dt.Rows.Count <> 0` will throw this exception:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: For anyone else finding this and wants to know more check out the answers at [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Preferred:

```
If dt Is Nothing Then ...
```

- [`Is`-Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb136x1y.aspx)
- [`Nothing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x9tb07z%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

or (VB6 like)

```
If IsNothing(dt) Then ...
```

[IsNothing Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5adx7fxz%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: hehe ... of course .. why was I being so silly just now ... Thanks .. :D

Comment: @LaurenceNyein your sillyness proved helpful to me :)

Answer (score 0):

dt2 = datatable
If dt2.Rows.Count > 0

Answer (score -1):

If the value datatype is varbinary(MAX), use

```
if dt.rows(0).item(2) Is DBNull.Value then...
```

Comment: Please re-read the question. It explicitly asks to check when a `DataTable` has not been set. That means your code will fail.